# How to expose all module classes through index.js in Node

Tags: node.js, module

I have a directory structure like this:

node_modules/mymodule/index.js :

```
module.exports = require('./lib/mymodule');
```

node_modules/mymodule/lib/mymodule.js

```
var A = require('./a'),

function MyModule(){
    var self = this;
    self.version = '0.0.1'; 
}

/**
 * Expose MyModule
 */
module.exports = MyModule;

/**
 * Expose A
 */
exports.A = A;
```

node_modules/mymodule/lib/a.js

```
function A(options) {
    console.log('A::constructor()');

};

User.prototype.test = function() {
    return "your test was successful";
};

module.exports = A;
```

My issue come with trying to instantiate A. In the node prompt I get this:

```
> var MyModule = require('mymodule');
undefined // why do I get undefined here ?
> var mymodule = new MyModule();
undefined
> var A = MyModule.A;
undefined
> var a = new A();
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at repl:1:9
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at repl.js:190:20
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:87:5)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `node_modules/mymodule/lib/mymodule.js` to:

```
var exports = module.exports = {
  version: '0.0.1'
}

exports.A = require('./a');
```

You can only have one `module.exports` ;)

Comment: I only have one. Do you mean I need to take `module.exports` out of a.js? Why have you changed my constructor to an Object? Was that on purpose?

Comment: In fact you had `exports.A` at the bottom, it can't work with `module.exports`. Yeah I wanted to change it to an object, but I forgot some step :P, I correct that right now. For your use I though that an object was easier to work with.

Comment: So basiclly, in order for this to work `module.exports = MyModule;` needs to be at the bottom?

Comment: No you can still make modification on myModule after the export, because object are passed by reference not by value. I edited my script again

Comment: And if you want to make it more compatible, you can replace all occurrences of `myModule` by `exports` in my code

Answer (score 0):

The node [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) will print the return value of the command, which in all of those cases is undefined. That doesn't mean your variables are undefined.

Try:

```
> var A = MyModule.A;
```

then

```
> A
```